# gnuplot set two keys side by side and share a title？

Tags: gnuplot

This is my figure:
[image: tu1]
I want to change the keys to this:
[image: lin]
Below is my code, what should I do?

```
set tmargin at screen 0.995;    # top and right usually close to 1
set rmargin at screen 0.995;
set bmargin at screen 0.05;
set lmargin at screen 0.05;

set xr[0:0.24]
set yr[0:0.24]
set xtics border offset   0,0.4 0,0.05,0.2
set ytics border offset   0.8,0 0,0.05,0.2
set xlabel 'RHS' offset 0,3
set ylabel 'LHS' offset 9,0

set key at 0.22,0.1

plot '-' w p ps 2 pt 11 lc 8 title "$\kappa$",\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 7 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 9 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 13 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 10 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 6 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 8 lc 8,\
     '-' w p ps 2 pt 12 lc 8,\
     x dashtype 2 lc 8
0.208555 0.204212
e
0.108604 0.107899
e
0.055720 0.055651
e
0.037514 0.037498
e
0.208555 0.230125
e
0.108604 0.115062
e
0.055720 0.057531
e
0.037514 0.038354
e
```

I didn't find a legend on how to do this juxtaposition in the website, hope someone can teach me.

Comment: Do you need the 'x' in the legend too or just the symbols?

Comment: @theozh Hi, I don't need a legend for "y=x", I just need to juxtapose points of the same shape, but I don't know how? do you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the key option `maxrows` (check `help key`). With this you can limit the number of rows in the legend, however, depending on whether you need a title for `x` you may need to play other tricks.
However, the horizontal space between the columns is rather large.
You could reduce the space for the symbol (actually line) in the legend via `samplen 0`
and use the option `reverse`, this would place the titles between the symbols, unfortunately not centered.
However, this still doesn't look too good, and even worse if your titles do not have the same length.

If you want to get the symbols closer, you could also use multiplot (check `help multiplot`) to overlay shifted legends, but I would call this rather cumbersome.

I minimized your script a little.

**Script:**

```
### shared title in legend
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.208555   0.204212

0.108604   0.107899

0.055720   0.055651

0.037514   0.037498

0.208555   0.230125

0.108604   0.115062

0.055720   0.057531

0.037514   0.038354
EOD

set xr[0:0.24]
set yr[0:0.24]
set xlabel 'RHS'
set ylabel 'LHS'

set key at graph 0.9, 0.4
set key maxrows 4 title "Legend title" offset -3,0.2 font ",13"
set key samplen 0 reverse

myPts      = "11 7 9 13 10 6 8 12"
myPt(i)    = int(word(myPts,i))
myTitles   = "title1 title2 title3 title4"
myTitle(i) = i>words(myTitles) ? ' ' : word(myTitles,i)."  "

plot for [i=1:8] $Data u 1:2 every :::i-1::i-1 w p ps 2 pt myPt(i) lc 8 ti myTitle(i), \
     x w l dt 2 lc 8 notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here would be the multiplot solution. Since you are using fixed margins in your original script anyway, it is not too much extra effort. You need to play with the graph coordinates of the second key to get the desired placement.

**Script:**

```
### shared title in legend using multiplot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.208555   0.204212

0.108604   0.107899

0.055720   0.055651

0.037514   0.037498

0.208555   0.230125

0.108604   0.115062

0.055720   0.057531

0.037514   0.038354
EOD

set xr[0:0.24]
set yr[0:0.24]
set xlabel 'RHS'
set ylabel 'LHS'

set margin 10,5,4,2

set key at graph 0.9, 0.4
set key title "Legend title" offset -3,0.2 font ",13"
set key samplen 0 reverse

myPts      = "11 7 9 13 10 6 8 12"
myPt(i)    = int(word(myPts,i))
myTitles   = "title1 title2 title3 title4"
myTitle(i) = i>words(myTitles) ? ' ' : ' '.word(myTitles,i)

set multiplot

    plot for [i=1:4] $Data u 1:2 every :::i-1::i-1 w p ps 2 pt myPt(i) lc 8 ti myTitle(i), \
        x w l dt 2 lc 8 notitle

    set key at graph 0.8,0.4 title " "
    unset border
    unset tics
    unset xlabel
    unset ylabel
    plot for [i=5:8] $Data u 1:2 ever :::i-1::i-1 w p ps 2 pt myPt(i) lc 8 ti " "

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also used the maxrows 4 option, but the space between the two column legends is very large, I tried to use set key width 20 but it seems to have this minimum width setting. Everything about the character settings is easy, I will save it as a TeX file, and modify the characters and their positions in TeX.

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang see the multiplot solution. This still might be easier than fiddling around with character positions in TeX.

Comment: This is my ideal image, thank you so much

Comment: Hi, since the border of the image is too wide, I would use `set bmargin at screen 0.04;
set lmargin at screen 0.04;` to reduce the width of the border, but in your code, this statement does not seem to work, how should I modify it?

Comment: I have solved it, don't bother you , thank you very much